# Consuming the return value of sp_start_job in .NET

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2

I hit a frustrating problem with the result of `sp_start_job` when I use it in a stored procedure, store its result in a variable, and select that variable to be consumed by .NET. It works perfectly when my SP is run in a Management Studio query window, so I'm at a loss as to what is wrong.

I have an object that is populated by the result set of my SP:

```cs
public class SQLServerAgentResult : StoredProcResult
{
    public int? JobStatus { get; set; }
    public int? JobStartResult { get; set; } //This is the property for the result of sp_start_job
    public int? LastJobResult { get; set; }
}
```

It is populated by this method using a data context:

```cs
public IList<SQLServerAgentResult> ExecuteSqlAgent(string JobName, bool? RunJob, TimeSpan? PollingInterval)
{
    const string myName = "usp_Run_Monitor_Agent_Job";

    List<SqlParameter> spParams = new List<SqlParameter>();

    spParams.Add(new SqlParameter()
    { 
        DbType = System.Data.DbType.String,
        ParameterName = "JobName",
        Value = JobName
    });
    string sp_exec = "usp_Run_Monitor_Agent_Job @JobName";

    if (RunJob != null)
    {
        spParams.Add(new SqlParameter()
        { 
            SqlDbType = System.Data.SqlDbType.Bit,
            DbType = System.Data.DbType.Boolean,
            ParameterName = "RunJob",
            Value = RunJob
        });
        sp_exec += ", @RunJob";
    }
    if (PollingInterval != null)
    {
        spParams.Add(new SqlParameter()
        {
            SqlDbType = System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar,
            DbType = System.Data.DbType.Time,
            ParameterName = "TimerDelay",
            Value = PollingInterval
        });
        sp_exec += ", @TimerDelay";
    }

    try
    {
        Context.CommandTimeout = 120;
        List<SQLServerAgentResult> result = Context.SQLServerAgentResult.SqlQuery(sp_exec, spParams.ToArray()).ToList();

        return result;

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        log.Error(myName + " error", ex);
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

It should be noted that this object is always populated with data from my stored procedure, and that `JobStatus` and `LastJobResult` are always correct. However, `JobStartResult`, which should contain the result for `sp_start_job`, only ever has the initialized value for the variable used in the stored procedure (in this case, the value null). This could be a valid result (the SP can decide to not run `sp_start_job`), but when `sp_start_job` is finished, the result does not seem to be saved to the variable and my object will contain the initialized value instead.

Here is my SQL Agent SP:

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE usp_Run_Monitor_Agent_Job @JobName NVARCHAR(MAX), @RunJob BIT = 1, @TimerDelay VARCHAR(50) = '00:00:01'
AS

DECLARE @JobStatus INT
DECLARE @JobStart INT
DECLARE @JobResult INT
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @Params NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @IsProcessing BIT

SET @JobStatus = 0  --Works fine in .NET
SET @JobStart = null --If this is initialized as -1, 5, or 43276852349, then that is the result I will see in .NET, without exception
SET @JobResult = 0  --Works fine in .NET
SET @IsProcessing = 0

SET @SQL = N'SELECT @JobStatus_OUT = current_execution_status FROM OPENROWSET(''SQLNCLI'', ''Server=localhost;Trusted_Connection=yes;'', ''EXEC MSDB.dbo.sp_help_job @job_name = ''''' + @JobName + ''''', @job_aspect = ''''JOB'''' '')'
SET @Params = N'@JobStatus_OUT INT OUTPUT'

--Check to see if the job is currently running
EXEC sp_executesql @SQL, @Params, @JobStatus_OUT = @JobStatus OUTPUT;

--Check to see if the job is idle
IF @JobStatus = 4
BEGIN
    --Check to see if we should run the job
    IF @RunJob = 1
    BEGIN
        --This next line is the problem. It runs, but @JobStart doesn't contain the result of the sp_start_job when run through .NET.
        EXEC @JobStart = MSDB.dbo.sp_start_job @Job_Name = @JobName
        SET @IsProcessing = 1
        WHILE @IsProcessing = 1
        BEGIN
            --Now we need to wait for the job to finish
            WAITFOR DELAY @TimerDelay
            EXEC sp_executesql @SQL, @Params, @JobStatus_OUT = @JobStatus OUTPUT;

            --4 is "idle"
            --5 is "suspended", which means the job isn't running but it won't be able to be re-executed either
            IF @JobStatus = 4 OR @JobStatus = 5
                SET @IsProcessing = 0
        END
    END
END

SET @SQL = N'SELECT TOP 1 @JobResult_OUT = run_status FROM OPENROWSET(''SQLNCLI'', ''Server=localhost;Trusted_Connection=yes;'', ''SET FMTONLY OFF; EXEC MSDB.dbo.sp_help_jobhistory @job_name = ''''' + @JobName + ''''', @mode = ''''FULL'''' '') WHERE step_id = 0 ORDER BY run_date DESC, run_time DESC;'
SET @Params = N'@JobResult_OUT AS INT OUTPUT'
EXEC sp_executesql @SQL, @Params, @JobResult_OUT = @JobResult OUTPUT;

--Return job statuses
SELECT CAST(1 AS BIGINT) AS ID, @JobStatus AS JobStatus, @JobStart AS JobStartResult, @JobResult AS LastJobResult
```

In the course of troubleshooting, I've attempted to manipulate the value of `@JobStart` after `sp_start_job` is executed. Again, I'm able to do so in SSMS and receive the expected results, but from .NET the variable will still contain the initialized value.

I'm open to any information that can explain why it works fine in SSMS and not in .NET, and how to get it to work in .NET. Thanks.

Comment: Can we see the .Net code that you are using to populate the property values of your class.  My guess is the culprit is there.

Comment: @RThomas, I'm not so sure. The other two fields, `JobStatus` and `LastJobResult` are populated just fine. However, the difference with them is that they are handled differently in the stored proc. Also, `JobStartResult` does get populated. If I initialize `@JobStart` with a value of, say, 2, then my `JobStartResult` property will have a value of 2. So, the object is certainly being populated.

Comment: I've tried executing sp_start_job dynamically and using output variables, but I get the same result. Works fine in SSMS but .NET only ever has the other two properties correct but `JobStartResult` is the initialized value.

Comment: It looks like using a data context to call my SP is the problem. Calling the stored procedure through ADO.NET correctly populates the `JobStartResult` in my object. Does it make any sense to anyone that a data context would be unable to capture the return results of stored procedures, even if those stored procs are embedded in another stored procedure that is being called?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I revamped my repository methods to use ADO.NET to call my stored procedure. Originally, I was using a data context to do so. For whatever reason, it now correctly populates `JobStartResult`. So, the code works as expected now.

However, I do not know *why* the stored procedure behaves differently when called via data context and called via ADO.NET.